# Solving a ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, thread-safety, concurrentmodification

I am writing a little game which has many circles moving on the screen.
I am managing the circles in two threads as following:

```
public void run() {
    int stepCount = 0;
    int dx;
    int dy;
    while (m_threadTrap){
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;

        synchronized (m_circles) {
            for (Iterator<Circle> it = m_circles.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
                Circle c = it.next(); //Exception thrown here.
                if (c.getDirX() != 0)
                    if (stepCount % c.getDirX() == 0){
                        dx = 1;
                    }
                if (c.getDirY() != 0)
                    if (stepCount % c.getDirY() == 0){
                        dy = 1;                 
                    }

                c.move(dx, dy); 
            }
        }
        if (stepCount == 150000){
            stepCount = 0;
        }
        stepCount++;
    }
}
```

m_circles in an ArrayList of Circles.

And the following Thread:

```
public void run() {
    while (m_threadTrap){
        int topPosition;
        int bottomPosition;
        int leftPosition;
        int rightPosition;
        ArrayList<Circle> removedCircles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
        synchronized (m_circles.getCircles()) {
            for (Iterator<Circle> it = m_circles.getCircles().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
                Circle c = it.next();

                // Some calculation to evaluate which circles should be removed
                    removedCircles.add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(25);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }

        m_circles.getCircles().removeAll(removedCircles);

        if (m_circles.getCircles().size() < 30)
            m_circles.addNewCircle();

        repaint(); 
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get ConcurrentModificationException at the line

```
Circle c = it.next();
```

in the first thread. At first I tried going over the ArrayList with a foreach loop and this gave me the same exception.
After researching a bit on this exception I saw two solutions:
 1. Putting the part which accesses the collection in a synchronized block.
 2. Using the Iterator object of the collection.
Neither of them solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `synchronized() {}` block to be effective, **all accesses to the protected objects** must be wrapped in synchronized blocks.  You probably forgot to wrap some access.

Another "gotcha" is that ConcurrentModificationException can also mean that it was concurrently modified *in the same thread*.  For example, if you remove an element from a collection while traversing it, you may get this exception.  (As an exception, you can safely remove elements via the iterator itself)

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed there was one more access point I forgot to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentModificationException means that you are iterating over a collection and, while iterating, someone (the current thread or another one) modified the underlying collection without using `Iterator.remove()`. Whenever you invoke an operation on the Iterator it checks that the underlying collection has not been changed. Using a foreach does not change a thing, since it uses an Iterator to perform the loop.

Your solution are:

1. create a new collection:

   for (Circle c: new ArrayList(m_circles.getCircles()).iterator()) {
          // Some calculation to evaluate which circles should be removed
          removedCircles.add(c);
   }
2. or synchronize both threads on the same object (you synchronize on different objects, therefore it does not do anything) whenever you are modifying or accessing the collection